# code behind c# - javascript - google map

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, button, maps

help! I have a google map in the master page , moving the map I get the coordinates then
Click  asp button through javascript I would update the data in the page content in the code behind c # . this works but it only works the first time , by moving the map again , the button is not clicked more
 this code:

page.aspx
 
                    
                        
                           Please wait ...

```
                <asp:Button ID="MapTrigger" name="MapTrigger" runat="server" OnClick="MapTrigger_Click" style="display:none;"  />
```

javascript:

```
function OnSuccess(resul_param) {
    if (resul_param) {
          document.getElementById("currentDate").innerHTML = resul_param[0];

          var clickButton = document.getElementById("<%=MapTrigger.ClientID %>");

          $('clickButton').trigger('click'); 
}
```

code behind c#.

```
protected void MapTrigger_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   .....       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this way. I have made ​​visible to the entire page ( MasterPage + aspx) button with a global function that I put at the beginning of the aspx page immediately after the tag Content

function InitializeVariables() {

         var MapTrigger = null;

         if (MapTrigger == null) {
             MapTrigger = document.getElementById("");
             MapTrigger.click();
         }
     }

now works perfectly.